# Change the URI pattern in UriComponentsBuilder

Tags: java, spring

In spring web jar, the class UriComponentsBuilder has below pattern defined,

```
private static final Pattern QUERY_PARAM_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([^&=]+)(=?)([^&]+)?");
```

I want to make the pattern edit and add use my custom pattern. So how can i do it? Is the only solution is edit the source and create a new web jar and use it?

Answer (score 0):

Normally we don't need to change the pattern, But if you still want

You can simply extend the class UriComponentsBuilder and override the methods where that pattern is used , seems only this query method is using the pattern.

```
public UriComponentsBuilder query(String query) {
        if (query != null) {
            Matcher matcher = QUERY_PARAM_PATTERN.matcher(query);
```

Something like this :

```
public class MyUriComponentsBuilder extends UriComponentsBuilder {

private static final Pattern MY_QUERY_PARAM_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([^&=]+)(=?)([^&]+)?");

  @Override   
  public UriComponentsBuilder query(String query) {
            if (query != null) {
                Matcher matcher = MY_QUERY_PARAM_PATTERN.matcher(query);
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks.  actually this method is called from another jar which is spring-data. In that case how to do it?